# unable to install package "MBESS"

Tags: r, installation, package

I have R version 3.6.1.
I want to install the package "MBESS" but I get this output
Can someone help me please?
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEVqX.png)

Comment: and when I try to install package "semTools" it says  package ‘semTools’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)... where can I download this version could not find a link

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please paste the error message in a **text format** rather than as an image/screenshot?

Comment: Your problem is that the most recent versions of most of these packages require more recent versions of R than you have (your version is quite old).  Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa/25721890#25721890) help?  If you don't **need** this old a version of R for some reason, the quickest and easiest solution will be to download a recent version.

Comment: @BenBolker I can not find the most recent version download link for R MacOS could you maybe send it to me? And yes next time I will paste the error message as text sorry didn't know, I am new here

Comment: You don't need to be sorry, that's why I told you.  https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

Comment: If your R is v. 3.6, you want package semTools v. 0.5.2. `remotes::install_version("semTools", "0.5.2")`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have R version 3.6 (the version of RStudio is totally irrelevant here, RStudio is just a pretty window interface to R).

Version 3.6 of R is very old, and its not surprising that some packages no longer run on it. Upgrade your version of R to the latest (4-point-something) and you should be okay to install anything from CRAN.

Alternatively you may have to work hard to get that dependent package running on your old R version, for example finding an older repository or finding the source code and building for your version. This can be difficult.

Comment: thank you I didn't know that Rstudio was only an interface for R